# Python: merging two lists where object "identity" isn't equality

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to merge two lists, `base` and `override`, where `base` is supposed to be a larger list and `override` is a subset of the things in `base`. Where the elements overlap, I want the object in `base` to be overwritten by the one in `override`. The objects in each list are namedtuples with attributes `al2000` and `de2000` among them. Moreover I want to treat the objects as being "identical" when they have the same `al2000` and `de2000` values. What I have (which seems to work) is below, but this has nested loops, and I'm wondering if there is a better way to do this.

```
# Part of a function
final = []
for i in base:
    if all((i.al2000, i.de2000) != (k.al2000, k.de2000) for k in override):
        final.append(i)
    else:
        for k in override:
            if (i.al2000, i.de2000) == (k.al2000, k.de2000):
                final.append(k)
return final
```

Comment: In which case would you actually overwrite an item in base with an item from override? Seems you only want to append missing items.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `for/else` construct.

```
final = []
for i in base:
    for k in override:
        if (i.al2000, i.de2000) == (k.al2000, k.de2000):
            # found an override
            final.append(k)
            break
    else:
        final.append(i)
```

This solution still uses a nested for-loop, but it removes code duplication from your original solution (iterating over `overrides`, the comparison of `i` and `k`).

Answer (score 1):

You could use a dictionary and a couple of dictionary comprehensions.

```
uniques = {(x.al2000, x.de2000): x for x in base}
uniques.update({(x.al2000, x.de2000): x for x in override})
final = uniques.values()
```

Edit to retain original behavior about omitting extra values in `override`.

```
uniques = {(x.al2000, x.de2000): x for x in base}
for value in override:
    key = value.al2000, value.de2000
    if key in uniques:
        uniques[key] = value
# here's the comprehension version, although it's a bit rough on the eyes
# uniques.update({(x.al2000, x.de2000): x for x in override if (x.al2000, x.de2000) in uniques})
final = uniques.values()
```

Comment: This is not equivalent to original code because (1) it does not preserve order (2) elements in `override` which do not appear in `base` are included in `final`. otherwise, a nice elegant solution!

Comment: I made an edit to address the second one. The first one cannot. Plus, depending on the size of `base`, maintaining a separate structure (i.e., `uniques`) could be memory intensive.

Answer (score 0):

since all you really want to do is look something up in overrides, make a dict out of it:

```
od = {(x.al2000, x.de2000): x for x in override}
```

now, just create the result:

```
res = [od.get((b.al2000, b.de2000), b) for b in base]
```

*not tested, but should be ok
*edited for dirn's suggestion

Comment: You could also pass `b` to `od.get`.

Comment: nope, because b has more attributes than just `al2000` and `de2000`

Comment: I meant `od.get((b.al2000, b.de2000), b)`.

Answer (score 0):

This answers adopts @acushner's suggestion to use a dict, which might be the most natural approach in your case. To add to it, when dealing with overrides, [`ChainMap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.ChainMap) is useful and in many cases the most natural way to represent your data structure.

```
from collections import ChainMap
base_dct = {(x.al2000, x.de2000): x for x in base}
override_dct = {(x.al2000, x.de2000): x for x in override}
z = ChainMap(base_dct, override_dct)
# then access:
z.values()
# or:
z[(x.al2000, x.de2000)]
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23392976/2096752) for more info about ChainMaps.