# Efficiently merge large collection of dictionaries

Tags: python, memory, optimization, dictionary

I have a multiprocessor program which basically parses some XML information and returns the dictionary (one dictionary object for a file) as output and then, I am merging all the dictionaries into one `final_dword`.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  numthreads = 2  
  pool = mp.Pool(processes=numthreads)
  dword_list = pool.map(parse_xml, (locate("*.xml")))
  final_dword = {}
  print "The final Word Count dictionary is "
  map(final_dword.update,dword_list)
  print final_dword
```

The above code works perfectly fine for smaller data sets. As my datasize is growing, my program freezes during

```
map(final_dword.update,dword_list)
```

This is my assumption that my program freezes during the exe of above stmt.  I tried to profile my code using muppy and found the following.

In *n* iteration (where *n* > 1200+, which means the program has basically processed around 1200+ files), I get the following stats:

> ```
> Iteration  1259
>                        types |   # objects |   total size
> ============================ | =========== | ============
>                         dict |         660 |    511.03 KB
>                          str |        6899 |    469.10 KB
>                         code |        1979 |    139.15 KB
>                         type |         176 |     77.00 KB
>           wrapper_descriptor |        1037 |     36.46 KB
>                         list |         307 |     23.41 KB
>   builtin_function_or_method |         738 |     23.06 KB
>            method_descriptor |         681 |     21.28 KB
>                      weakref |         434 |     16.95 KB
>                        tuple |         476 |     15.76 KB
>                          set |         122 |     15.34 KB
>          <class 'abc.ABCMeta |          18 |      7.88 KB
>          function (__init__) |         130 |      7.11 KB
>            member_descriptor |         226 |      7.06 KB
>            getset_descriptor |         213 |      6.66 KB
> ```

I have 4 Gb RAM in my laptop and I am processing huge number of small (< 1MB) XML files.
I am looking for a better way to merge the smaller dictionaries.

Comment: do you have to map it to a filan dword?

Comment: You could try just `dict(itertools.chain.from_iterable(x.iteritems() for x in dword_list))`.

Comment: @user1767754 Ahh not really. All I want is a dictionary which constitutes all the intermediate dictionaries. If there is any alternative you have, let me know.

Comment: @roippi I ll try that and get back on this.

Comment: @roippi I dont think this works. I am getting empty dict as the output. Not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Python 3.3 you could try if collections.ChainMap would be a solution for you. I have not used it yet, but it is supposed to be a quick way to link multiple dictionaries together. See the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23392976/what-is-the-purpose-of-collections-chainmap).

Maybe try to pickle dword_list to a file, and use a generator instead of keeping the list memory. In that way you stream the data instead of storing it. It should free some memory and make the program faster. Something like:

```
def xml_dict(): 
    for d in pickle.load("path/to/file.pickle"): 
        yield d
```

Comment: Well, I am using python 2.X  :(

Comment: Maybe try a generator instead of storing the whole list. See the edited post.

Comment: Is there anyway, I can merge the dictionaries while they are being output by the process ( n =2 , in this case). I can save space in memory and dont have to pickle it.

Comment: Did you have a look at the collections module, [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) could be useful. It is supposed to be high performance. Or maybe [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects).

Comment: It still takes quite a while to update the dictionary and usually I run out of memory by then.  I need to merge the elements (dicts) ofthe list as and when the parallel process updates them. that would atleast in theory be the fastest way of merging. But I am not sure, how to do that.

Comment: Okay, that is a problem. You need a shared dictionary and add items to it with parse_xml. I have never done this, but I just came across processing.Manager maybe that is useful. The idea is to create a shared dictionary. [Here is an example](http://pymotw.com/2/multiprocessing/communication.html#managing-shared-state)

Answer (score 0):

Using `itertools` you can chain containers

```
import itertools

listA = {1,2,3}
listB = {4,5,6}
listC = {7,8,9}

for key in itertools.chain(listA, listB, listC):
    print key,
```

Output: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

This way you don't need to create a new container, it will run over the iterables until they are exhausted. It is the same as the user @roippi commented, but written differently.

```
dict(itertools.chain.from_iterable(x.iteritems() for x in dword_list))
```