# Python 3 map dictionary update method to a list of other dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, dictionary, map-function

In Python 2 I can do the following:

```
>> d = {'a':1}
>> extras = [{'b':2}, {'c':4}]
>> map(d.update, extras)
>> d['c']
>> 4
```

In Python 3 in get a `KeyError`:

```
>> d = {'a':1}
>> extras = [{'b':2}, {'c':4}]
>> map(d.update, extras)
>> d['c']
>> KeyError: 'c'
```

I would like to achieve the same behavior in Python 3 as in Python 2.

I understand that map in Python 3 will return an iterator (lazy evaluation and whatnot), which has to be iterated for the dictionary to be updated.

I had assumed the `d['c']` key lookup would trigger the map iteration somehow, which is not the case.

Is there a pythonic way to achieve this behavior without writing a for loop,
which I find to be verbose compared to map.

I have thought of using list comprehensions:

```
>> d = {'a':1}
>> extras = [{'b':2}, {'c':4}]
>> [x for x in map(d.update, extras)]
>> d['c']
>> 4
```

But it does not seem pythonic.

Comment: `list(map(d.update, extras))` will force the iterator to be consumed

Comment: The pythonic way *is* to use a for loop!  Using map (or a list comprehension) for its side effects rather than its results is definitely *not* pythonic.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As you note, `map` in Python 3 creates an iterator, which doesn't (in and of itself) cause any `update`s to occur:

```
>>> d = {'a': 1}
>>> extras = [{'b':2}, {'c':4}]
>>> map(d.update, extras)
<map object at 0x105d73c18>
>>> d
{'a': 1}
```

To force the `map` to be fully evaluated, you could pass it to `list` explicitly:

```
>>> list(map(d.update, extras))
[None, None]
>>> d
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 4}
```

---

However, as the relevant section of [What's new in Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#views-and-iterators-instead-of-lists) puts it:

> Particularly tricky is `map()` invoked for the side effects of the
>   function; the correct transformation is to use a regular `for` loop
>   (since creating a list would just be wasteful).

In your case, this would look like:

```
for extra in extras:
    d.update(extra)
```

which doesn't result in an unnecessary list of `None`.

Comment: that for loop was just going bite me! thanks anyway

Comment: Note: instead of `list` one can use `collections.deque(iterable, maxlen=0)` to consume the `iterable` without consuming memory. This also executes only one bytecode so should be slightly more time efficient than an explicit `for` at least in CPython.

Comment: @Bakuriu interesting, I wouldn't have thought of doing that; I didn't know a `deque` *could* have a zero maximum length!

Comment: brilliant explanation

Answer (score 1):

Alongside the @jonrsharpe's explanation that explains the problem clearly In Python 3 you can use [`collections.ChainMap`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/collections.html#collections.ChainMap) for such tasks:

```
>>> from collections import ChainMap
>>> chain=ChainMap(d, *extras)
>>> chain
ChainMap({'a': 1}, {'b': 2}, {'c': 4})
>>> chain['c']
4
```

But note that if there are duplicate keys, the values from the *first* mapping get used.

Read more about the advantages of using ChainMap :[What is the purpose of collections.ChainMap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23392976/what-is-the-purpose-of-collections-chainmap)