# append multiple dictionaries into one dictionary sequentially in python

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have several dictionaries like this

```
dict1 = {0: 33.422, 1: 39.2308, 2: 30.132}
dict2 = {0: 42.2422, 1: 43.342, 2: 42.424}
dict3 = {0: 13.422, 1: 9.2308, 2: 20.132}
```

I am aware that I could combine them together into one dictionary using the code

```
dicts = dict1, dict2, dict3
```

And it returns the result like this

```
({0: 33.422, 1: 39.2308, 2: 30.132}, {0: 42.2422, 1: 43.342, 2: 42.424}, {0: 13.422, 1: 9.2308, 2: 20.132})
```

However, what if the dictionaries come sequentially? How can I get the same results? I tried the following code

```
dicts = {}
dicts = dicts, dict1
dicts = dicts, dict2
dicts = dicts, dict3
```

But it returns the result like this

```
((({}, {0: 33.422, 1: 39.2308, 2: 30.132}), {0: 42.2422, 1: 43.342, 2: 42.424}), {0: 13.422, 1: 9.2308, 2: 20.132})
```

How can we remove the first stuff? I'm using python 3 on windows 7. And all the dictionaries are in a "MyDataFileReader" type under avro package.

Comment: `dicts = dict1, dict2, dict3` will create a tuple and not a dictionary ... So what you are doing is just making tuples of tuples

Comment: When using the 'double assignment' `dict = dicts, dict1`, essentially you are creating a `tuple`. Tuples are immutable and therefore you cant add anything to it with the following lines (`dicts = dicts, dict2` etc.) it simply creates a new tuple containing the old tuple. I'm not sure what you want as a final datatype. Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: What do you need the data to look like in the end? Are you just looking to combine multiple dictionaries?

Comment: You can't append to a dictionary. `dict` keys are unique so you can't just add another one to the end. In your example, each dict has a `0` key. If you combine the dicts, what do you want to happen to these keys (what should happen to `0: 33.422` `0: 42.2422`  and `0: 13.422`)?

Comment: [ChainMap](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23392976/2096752) can be useful in cases like this.

Comment: @Tracy Yang: what result are you looking for? would be nice to know that. Also, check the first solution given below, depends on the solution desired, you have some of them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want a list of dictionaries:

```
dict1 = {0: 33.422, 1: 39.2308, 2: 30.132}
dict2 = {0: 42.2422, 1: 43.342, 2: 42.424}
dict3 = {0: 13.422, 1: 9.2308, 2: 20.132}
dicts = []
dicts.append(dict1)
dicts.append(dict2)
dicts.append(dict3)
```

Answer (score 6):

As @MMF already stated in his comment: `a, b, c` creates a tuple containing `a`, `b` and `c` (in that order).

What you want to do, is "updating" the dictionary:

```
dict = {}
dict.update(dict1)
dict.update(dict2)
dict.update(dict3)
```

Or, if you don't want that `dict3` or `dict2` overwrite stuff:

```
dict = {}
dict.update(dict3)
dict.update(dict2)
dict.update(dict1)
```

Or

```
def update_without_overwriting(d, x):
    dict.update({k: v for k, v in x.items() if k not in d})

dict = {}
update_without_overwriting(dict, dict1)
update_without_overwriting(dict, dict2)
update_without_overwriting(dict, dict3)
```

If you just want a tuple containing all dicts however, use this:

```
dict = dict1, dict2
dict += dict3,
```

Answer (score -1):

From the first part of your examples, it appears you're trying to get a tuple of dictionaries, and not a dict of dicts. So try this:

```
dicts = ()
dicts = dicts + (dict1,)
dicts = dicts + (dict2,)
dicts = dicts + (dict3,)
```

Note that the trailing comma is required...