# Fill dictionary with value from the same row, but different column

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

Lately I've been trying to map some values, so I'm trying to create a dictionary to do so. The odd thing is my DataFrame has a column made of lists, and DataFrames are always a bit awkward with lists. The DataFrame has the following structure:

```
    rules          procedure
['10','11','12']       1
['13','14']            2
['20','21','22','24']  3
```

So I want to create a dictionary that maps '10' to 1, '14' to 2, and so on. I tried the following:

```
dicc=dict()
for j in df['rules']:
    for i,k in zip(j,df.procedure):
        dicc[i]=k
```

But that isn't making it. Probably something to do with indexes. What am I missing?

Edit: I'm trying to create a dictionary that maps the values '10', '11', '12' to 1; '13','14' to 2; '20','21','22','24' to 3, so if I type`dicc['10']` I get `1`, if I type`dicc['22']` I get `3`. Obviously, the actual DataFrame is quite bigger and I can't do it manually.

Comment: I'd start with a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) including input/output/expected output.

Comment: Just trying to make sure I understand exactly. The value in the corresponding `procedure` column indicates the index of the list that you'd like to do something with? Do what with exactly?

Comment: IIUC, you want to create a dictionary from this dataframe, so that the keys are taken from the lists in the `rules` column and the associated values are from the `procedure` column?

Comment: rahl23 you understood correctly indeed. I tried to clarify a bit in my edit

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [[['10', '11', '12'], 1],
        [['13', '14'], 2],
        [['20', '21', '22', '24'], 3]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['rules', 'procedure'])

d = {r : p for rs, p in df[['rules', 'procedure']].values for r in rs}
print(d)
```

**Output**

```
{'20': 3, '10': 1, '11': 1, '24': 3, '14': 2, '22': 3, '13': 2, '12': 1, '21': 3}
```

**Notes:**

- The code `{r : p for rs, p in df[['rules', 'procedure']].values for r
  in rs}` is a dictionary comprehension, the dictionary counterpart of
  list.
- The `df[['rules', 'procedure']].values` is equivalent to
  `zip(df.rules, df.procedure)` it outputs a pair of list, int. So the
  `rs` variable is a list and `p` is an integer.
- Finally you iterate over the values of `rs` using the second for loop

**UPDATE**

As suggested for @piRSquared you can use zip:

```
d = {r : p for rs, p in zip(df.rules, df.procedure) for r in rs}
```

Comment: This is as pythonic as it gets. It actually worked like a charm! Only issue is I'm not quite understanding the code. Would it be asking too much to ask for a little explanation of what is going on here?

Comment: I would try to explain!

Comment: Using `values` is not the most generalized way to do this.  In some cases, can cause problems.  I'd do this for your solution `{i: j for I, j in zip(df.rules, df.procedure) for i in I}`

Answer (score 6):

#### Help from `cytoolz`

```
from cytoolz.dicttoolz import merge

merge(*map(dict.fromkeys, df.rules, df.procedure))

{'10': 1,
 '11': 1,
 '12': 1,
 '13': 2,
 '14': 2,
 '20': 3,
 '21': 3,
 '22': 3,
 '24': 3}
```

---

#### Note

I updated my post to mimic how @jpp passed multiple iterables to `map`.  [@jpp's answer is very good](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52724364/2336654).  Though I'd advocate for upvoting all useful answers, I wish I could upvote their answer again (-:

Answer (score 5):

Using [`collections.ChainMap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.ChainMap):

```
from collections import ChainMap

res = dict(ChainMap(*map(dict.fromkeys, df['rules'], df['procedure'])))

print(res)

{'10': 1, '11': 1, '12': 1, '13': 2, '14': 2,
 '20': 3, '21': 3, '22': 3, '24': 3}
```

For many uses, the final `dict` conversion is not necessary:

> A `ChainMap` class is provided for quickly linking a number of
>   mappings so they can be treated as a single unit. It is often much
>   faster than creating a new dictionary and running multiple `update()`
>   calls.

See also [What is the purpose of collections.ChainMap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23392976/what-is-the-purpose-of-collections-chainmap)

Comment: `ChainMap` be new to me.  Thanks

Comment: Actually, I learned that you can pass multiple iterables as additional arguments within `map`.  I learned 2 things from this post.  Wish I had two votes (-: I updated my post because of this.

Answer (score 2):

You may check flatten the list

```
dict(zip(sum(df.rules.tolist(),[]),df.procedure.repeat(df.rules.str.len())))
Out[60]: 
{'10': 1,
 '11': 1,
 '12': 1,
 '13': 2,
 '14': 2,
 '20': 3,
 '21': 3,
 '22': 3,
 '24': 3}
```

Answer (score 1):

using `itertools.chain` and `DataFrame.itertuples`:

```
dict(
    chain.from_iterable(
        ((rule, row.procedure) for rule in row.rules) for row in df.itertuples()
    )
)
```