# Python multidimensional list combine

Tags: python

I want to combine the elements in the multidimensional list.

I have a list the below

```
[
  [
    { 'name': 'q' },
    { 'surname': 'w' },
    { 'email': 'e' }
  ],
  [
    { 'name': 'a' },
    { 'surname': 's' },
    { 'email': 'd' }
  ]
]
```

I want to list to be like this;

```
[
  { 
   'name': 'q',
   'surname': 'w',
   'email': 'e'
  },
  { 
    'name': 'a',
    'surname': 's',
    'email': 'd'
  }
]
```

How can I do this with Python? Can you help me please?
Thanks.

Comment: your question is vague, the example you provide is the final result you hope to get from your program, but you are not providing a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `collections.ChainMap` to transform each inner list into a single dict ([What is the purpose of collections.ChainMap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23392976/what-is-the-purpose-of-collections-chainmap)), and run that in a list comprehension:

```
data = [
  [
    { 'name': 'q' },
    { 'surname': 'w' },
    { 'email': 'e' }
  ],
  [
    { 'name': 'a' },
    { 'surname': 's' },
    { 'email': 'd' }
  ]
]

from collections import ChainMap

newdata = [dict(ChainMap(*item)) for item in data]
newdata
```

gives

```
[{'email': 'e', 'surname': 'w', 'name': 'q'},
 {'email': 'd', 'surname': 's', 'name': 'a'}]
```

Comment: This is very concise if performance is not considered, but in fact, its efficiency is terrible, because its iteration will concatenate all dict keys, and the `__getitem__` method has O(n) (n is the number of dictionaries) complexity.

Answer (score 2):

You just seem to want to merge multiple dictionaries:

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> from operator import ior
>>> [reduce(ior, mps, {}) for mps in lst]
[{'name': 'q', 'surname': 'w', 'email': 'e'},
 {'name': 'a', 'surname': 's', 'email': 'd'}]
```

Here, `reduce` is a shortcut to merge all dictionaries with a for loop, which is basically equivalent to:

```
>>> def merge_dicts(dicts):
...     res = {}
...     for mp in dicts:
...         res |= mp
...     return res
... 
>>> [merge_dicts(mps) for mps in lst]
[{'name': 'q', 'surname': 'w', 'email': 'e'},
 {'name': 'a', 'surname': 's', 'email': 'd'}]
```

Because the merge uses the in place operator, there is no extra overhead.

Comment: Can you explain what's happening here?

Comment: @iced I added the equivalent for loop code.

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way, in my opinion. It only works if you know the number of items in your inner lists.

```
new_list = []
for l in my_list:
  d = dict(**(l[0]), **(l[1]), **(l[2]))
  new_list.append(d)
```

if you don't know the number of items, you can use:

```
new_list = []
for l in my_list:
  d = {}
  for i in l:
    d.update(i)
  new_list.append(d)
```

Comment: That second sentence makes this a tricky solution. Or in case there are, say, 15 items in a single dict.

Comment: I totally agree with you and edited my answer to provide a reusable way.