# update method of python dictionary did not work

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two dictionaries.

```
a = {"ab":3, "bd":4}
b = {"cd":3, "ed":5}`
```

I want to combine them to `{'bd': 4, 'ab': 3, 'ed': 5, 'cd': 3}`.

As [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577234/python-extend-for-a-dictionary) says, `a.update(b)` can complete it. But when I try, I get:

```
type(a.update(b)) #--> type 'NoneType'
```

Would anyone like to explain it to me why I cannot gain a dict type?

I also tried this, and it did well:

```
type(dict(a,**b)) #-->type 'dict'
```

What is the difference between these two methods and why did the first one not work?

Comment: it doesn't return a 3rd dictionary, it updates in place.

Comment: You mean I cannot store the result in a third variable?

Comment: You can, but it will be `None`.

Comment: @wanglan You can with your second method.

Comment: Why the down votes? This was a very frustrating thing to figure out for me as well. In coming from other languages I fully expected `mydict.update(otherdict)` to return a reference to a dict until I learned about the python variable name and object model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a new Python user this was a very frequent "gotcha" for me as I always seemed to forget it.

As you have surmised, `a.update(b)` returns `None`, just as `a.append(b)` would return `None` for a list. These kinds of methods (`list.extend` is another) update the data structure *in place*.

Assuming you don't actually want `a` to be modified, try this:

```
c = dict(a)  # copy a
c.update(b)  # update a using b
type(c)  #returns a dict
```

That should do it.

Another other way of doing it, which is shorter:

```
c = dict(a,**b)
type(c)  #returns a dict
```

What is happening here is `b` is being unpacked. This will only work if the keys of `b` are all strings, since what you are *actually* doing is this:

```
c = dict(a, cd=3, ed=5)
type(c)  #returns a dict
```

Note that for any of the methods above, if any of the keys in `a` are duplicated in `b`, the `b` value will replace the `a` value, e.g.:

```
a = {"ab":3, "bd":4}
c = dict(a, ab=5)
c  #returns  {"ab":5, "bd":4}
```

Answer (score 9):

The `update` method updates a dict *in-place*. It returns `None`, just like `list.extend` does. To see the result, look at the dict that you updated.

```
>>> a = {"ab":3, "bd":4}
>>> b = {"cd":3, "ed":5}
>>> update_result = a.update(b)
>>> print(update_result)
None
>>> print(a)
{'ed': 5, 'ab': 3, 'bd': 4, 'cd': 3}
```

---

If you want the result to be a third, separate dictionary, you shouldn't be using `update`. Use something like `dict(a, **b)` instead, which, as you've already noticed, constructs a new dict from the two components, rather than *updating* one of the existing ones.

Answer (score 3):

`dict.update()` returns `None`, just like most methods that modify a container in place (`list.append()`, `list.sort()`, `set.add()` etc). That's by design so you don't get fooled into thinking it creates a new `dict` (or `list` etc).