# Cannot understand how to append sub-nested dictionary with additional dictionary in FOR cycle

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have `FOR` cycle for adding new  value items and my data structure consist of nested dictionaries like this:

```
d = {
    'item1': {
        'id1': {'a': 1}, 
        'id2': {'b': 2}
    }, 
    'item2': {
        'id7': {'o': 1}, 
        'id9': {'k': 2}
    }
}
```

I cannot understand how to append value of `'item1'` with some dictionary data like this `{'id3': {'z': 3}}` (new data)

When I'm trying to update existing value (adding new sub-value) -

```
d['item1'] = {'id3': {'z': 3}}
```

the whole value is replacing with new data

**So, the question is how to append existing sub-nested dictionary with new dictionary?**

**UPDATE**

```
items = {item1, item2, item3}
d = {}
for item in items:

    id = item['id']
    name = item['name']
    description = item['description']
    language = item['language']

    d[language] = {id: {'name': name, 'description': description}}
```

As you can see on each iteration I'm replacing existing `d[language]` value for every item in items.
But I would like to update value in the way to append value with data for each item.

**Can you please tell me how to achieve that?**

Comment: `d['item1']['id3'] = ...`

Comment: try to [update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577234/python-extend-for-a-dictionary) a dictionary

Comment: It was almost impossible to read that dictionary, cleaned it up a bit.

Comment: I think I have to edit my question, and provide actual code, because I have a difficulties with it. I did exactly like Robin said and I've got KeyError.

Comment: @RobinZigmond Question has been updated

Comment: The question has been marked as duplicate (although not by me), it's probably best if you ask a new question if you've looked at the linked questions and you feel your question hasn't been answered. And you're going to have to give more detail (your input, the output you want, and the output you're actually getting) in order to get a helpful answer.

Comment: @RobinZigmond Thank you, Robin!