# Python - Join two lists of dictionaries on a contains, and leave out any that do not match?

Tags: python

Im trying to join two list of dictionaries where one of the fields contains a section of another field, and if there isn't a match to lave it out.

```
list_1 = [{
    "bytes_in": 0,
    "rsrq": -50,
    "hostname": "AB9472"
},
{
    "bytes_in": 0,
    "rsrq": -90,
    "hostname": "DF4845"
},
{
    "bytes_in": 0,
    "rsrq": "None",
    "hostname": "FC4848"
}
]

list_2 = [{
    "id": 249,
    "ref_no": "AB9472 - 015632584",
    "rssi": "-75.0",
    "circuit_type": "4G"
},
{
    "id": 17,
    "ref_no": "DF4845 - 8984494",
    "rssi": "-20.0",
    "circuit_type": "4G"
}]
```

so in the above example list_1 hostname field would be contained inside list_2 ref_no and would match for the first two records and then be created in a new list_3

I feel I can do this in iterrtools but I'm not sure how?
Thanks

desired output:

```
list_3 = [{
    "id": 249,
    "ref_no": "AB9472 - 015632584",
    "rssi": "-75.0",
    "circuit_type": "4G",
    "bytes_in": 0,
    "rsrq": -50,
    "hostname": "AB9472"
},
{
    "id": 17,
    "ref_no": "DF4845 - 8984494",
    "rssi": "-20.0",
    "circuit_type": "4G",
    "bytes_in": 0,
    "rsrq": -90,
    "hostname": "DF4845"
}]
```

Comment: Could you please add an expected output?

Comment: Hi, I've added that, thank you

Comment: And does it have to use itertools?

Comment: Do you know ahead the names of the fields in question? i..e what if the `id` accidentally appears in the `hostname`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
list_3 = []
for i in list_1:
    for j in list_2:
        if i['hostname'] == j['ref_no'].split("-")[0].strip():
            list_3.append({**i,**j})

print(list_3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question basically is `extend` a dictionary by another dictionary.

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/577241/10034612), I suggest that you can use `dict1.update(dict2)`.

This is an example code for your issue when each element of the first list matched with each one of the second list.

```py
# Both lists have matched order
len2 = len(list_2)   # Use length of list_2 because it shorter
list_3=list_1[:len2] # list_3 contains 2 first elements of list_1
for i in range(len2):
    list_3[i].update(list_2[i])  # Each element is a dict, so use .update() for join 2 dicts
```

Comment: @FZs, I updated some description. Thanks for remind.

Answer (score 1):

Working off the assumption that you're basically doing a 'join' on `hostname` and the first portion of `ref_no` (with the same format for `ref_no`) I would propose the following procedure (using Pandas to do heavy lifting):

```
# Convert to pandas dataframes to abstract the merging
import pandas as pd
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(list_1)
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(list_2)

# Extract the hostname for merging
df_2['hostname'] = df_2['ref_no'].apply(lambda x: x.split(' - ')[0])

# Merge the dataframes - using outer-join to keep all information
# User inner to remove those that have no matches
df_3 = pd.merge(df_1, df_2, how='outer', on='hostname')

# Convert back to a list
list_3 = df_3.to_dict('records')
```

Answer (score 0):

iterating through list_2 and getting values from list_1 when hostname matched:

```
list_3 = list_2
for dataDict1 in list_3:
    refNo = dataDict1["ref_no"].split()[0]
    print(refNo)
    for dataDict2 in list_1:
        if refNo == dataDict2["hostname"]:
            dataDict1["hostname"] = refNo
            dataDict1["rsrq"] = dataDict2["rsrq"]
            dataDict1["bytes_in"] = dataDict2["bytes_in"]
            break
print(list_3)
```

output:

```
[{'bytes_in': 0,
  'circuit_type': '4G',
  'hostname': 'AB9472',
  'id': 249,
  'ref_no': 'AB9472 - 015632584',
  'rsrq': -50,
  'rssi': '-75.0'},
 {'bytes_in': 0,
  'circuit_type': '4G',
  'hostname': 'DF4845',
  'id': 17,
  'ref_no': 'DF4845 - 8984494',
  'rsrq': -90,
  'rssi': '-20.0'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list_1 = [{
    "bytes_in": 0,
    "rsrq": -50,
    "hostname": "AB9472"
},
{
    "bytes_in": 0,
    "rsrq": -90,
    "hostname": "DF4845"
},
{
    "bytes_in": 0,
    "rsrq": "None",
    "hostname": "FC4848"
}
]

list_2 = [{
    "id": 249,
    "ref_no": "AB9472 - 015632584",
    "rssi": "-75.0",
    "circuit_type": "4G"
},
{
    "id": 17,
    "ref_no": "DF4845 - 8984494",
    "rssi": "-20.0",
    "circuit_type": "4G"
}]

list_3 = []

for fs in list_1:
    for sl_fs in list_2:
        if sl_fs['ref_no'].split()[0] == fs['hostname']:
            list_3.append({**sl_fs, **fs})
```