# Dictionary update replaces original values instead

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

Whenever I receive a new url, I try to add that in my dictionary, along with the current time.
However, when I use the `update()` method, it replaces original values with the new values I added, so that the only thing in the dictionary now are the new values (and not the old ones).

Here is a shorter version of my code:

```
    if domain not in lst:
        lst.append(domain)
        domaindict = {} 
        listofdomains.append(domaindict)
        domaindict.update({domain:datetime.now().strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')})
    if domain in lst:
        domindex = lst.index(domain) 
        listofdomains[domindex].update({domain:datetime.now().strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')})
```

`lst` is the list of domain *names* so far, while `listofdomains` is the list that contains all the dictionaries of the separate domains (each dictionary has the domain name plus the time).

When I try to print listofdomains:

```
print(listofdomains)
```

It only prints out the newly added domain and urls in the dictionaries. I also tried to use other methods to update a dictionary, as detailed in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577234/python-extend-for-a-dictionary), but my dictionaries are still not functioning properly.

**Why did the original key/value pairs dissapear?**

Comment: Because you always use the same `domain` key, so you just replace the value. You can't have duplicate keys in a dict. You should probably reconsider your data structure - maintaining two parallel lists is probably not a very good idea...

Comment: According to documentation, the dict.update method updates the contents of the dictionary with new data.  Thus, the dictionary only contains the last updated value.  If you want produce a list of entries, you need to add to the dictionary value not update based on the key.

Comment: @itprorh66 how do I achieve that then?

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Thank you so much!!!!! I finally figured out a solution after you told me that; switching the keys and values so that the new keys don't repeat. Thank you!!!

Comment: That all depends on what you want to do, currently you are creating a dictionary for each domain with a key defined as the string determined by ```domain:datetime.now().strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')``` with no value.  and listofDomains contains a list of dicts each with a single timestring key.  What is it you are trying to keep track of and later access?

Comment: I'm trying to keep track of the domains I visited and record when I visited them and for how long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest structure would probably be a dict of lists:

```
data = {domain1:[time1, time2, ...], domain2:[...] ...}
```

You can build it simply using a defaultdict that creates empty lists on the fly when needed. Your code would be:

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = defaultdict(list)
```

and your whole code becomes simply:

```
data[domain].append(datetime.now().strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'))
```